# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment dark theme is not applying

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat, bottom-sheet

My problem is BottomSheetDialogFragment is not using dark theme. I can manually change the theme from OnCreateView but it breaks the animation of the bottomsheetdialog and root view is disappearing. Need help.

```
public class FilterBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment 
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //if (ThemeService.GetTheme(Context) == ThemeService.THEME_LIGHT)
        //{
        //    inflater.Context.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme_Light);
        //}
        //else if (ThemeService.GetTheme(Context) == ThemeService.THEME_DARK)
        //{
        //    inflater.Context.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme_Dark);
        //}

        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.filter_bottomsheet_dialog_alternate, container, false);
    }  
}
```

This is how I call the dialogfragment from mainActivity;

```
FilterBottomSheetFragment filterBottomSheetFragment = new FilterBottomSheetFragment();
filterBottomSheetFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "filterBottomSheetFragment");
```

Activities inherit from the BaseActivity.

```
public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ThemeService.GetTheme(this) == ThemeService.THEME_LIGHT)
        {
            SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme_Light);
        }
        else if (ThemeService.GetTheme(this) == ThemeService.THEME_DARK)
        {
            SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme_Dark);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All the activities inherit from the BaseActivity. BaseActivity added to description.

Comment: If I inherit FilterBottomSheetFragment from AppCompatDialogFragment instead of BottomSheetDialogFragment styling problem fixed. But it turns to normal dialog.